# Maximum number of generic lists in a package?

Tags: generics, delphi-xe2

I added a new unit to an existing (rather large) designtime package. When I tried to install this package i got an "access violation in rtl160.bpl". The same exception is thrown, when I load the package at runtime using "loadpackage".

I was able to boil the code in my new unit down to

```
interface
uses
  System.Generics.Collections;
type
  TMyList = TList< TObject>;
end;
```

and still got the error. When I removed the type declaration of the generic list everything worked fine. 
Further experiments showed that removing **any** declaration of a generic list **anywhere** in the package fixed the exception. Adding another generic list made the exception reappear.
So for each new generic list I added I had to remove another.

The same effect happens when I use a TObjectList instead. It does **not** happen, when I changed it to an TArray.

Is there really a maximum number of generic list one can declare within one package?! Has anybody further information?

Has anyone experienced a similar effect?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: There's no maximum number of these types. It's just surely a bug in that version. Which was pretty bug ridden in the generics code. Easiest thing is probably to remove the type alias because just don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply; unfortunately the exception still happens when i remove the alias ```unit Unit1;

 

interface

 

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

 

type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FMyList : TList< TObject>;
  end;
 ```

Comment: OK, so the problem isn't quite as you stated. Realistically, XE2 and generics is a futile battle. Give up. Upgrade.